# How to configure the camera to adjust the width and height

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem when ajust camera in Unity3D. When I build the APK and the game view too the width of the screen  is too much larger and if i increase the hight the width increase too. I tried to ajust throught code but i can't or samething i doing wrong . ¿Is possible to create a canvas and ajust the size of the camera to this?.
Or other method that i can ajust the camera to a square(image or anithing else that let me ajust the camera)

As you can see in the image the height is ok... but the width no is too mauch larger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftj94.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> Copied answer from answers.unity.com

In your ***Canvas*** you'll add a ***Canvas Scaler Component***. Then you will change the UI Scale Mode to Scale With Screen Size.

You have to put the Reference Resolution you work with, and then you have to change the Screen Match Mode to ***Shrink***.

Try now adjusting the Game Scene Screen, or compile in your mobile.

I recommend change the Default Orientation to Landscape in the PlayerSettings ***(Edit>Project Settings> Player)***.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me. It would be possible to make the camera view equal to the size of a gameobject. An image that I have in the background.